# How to get rid of index.php?

Tags: permalinks, site-url

Does anyone know how I can get rid of index.php in my URL?
Right now if I add a new page, the address will be:

www.mywebsite.com/index.php/page1

But I want it to be:

wwww.mywebsite.com/page1

I surfed the web a lot! Changing the permalink doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classical case. All you need to do is to use Rewrite Rules. With Apache, you can do it in .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

More on this in [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Comment: If setting RewriteRule in `.htaccess` doesn't work, then make sure your apache configuration is set properly. `AllowOverride All` instead of `AllowOverride None`. Check [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked after changing both .htaccess and apache configuration.

Comment: wordpress for my other website resides at /var/www/html/wordpress/ (and not at /var/www/html/) and the solution didn't work for this one. Do you know why? And how I can fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first try to change the permalinks in general setting of you website dashboard.....if not then you have to edit your .htaccess file....hope this will help to resolve the issue..!!

Comment: Without the permalink setting from `wp-admin` you'll get URL like `http://example.com/?p=N`. So it's definitely not that.

Answer (score 0):

I was also a victim of this error.But Now have solved the issue in CWP permalink index.php remove solution as follow:

Create a .htacess file in the root directory of your website /public_html/yoursite.com

Write the following code in it

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

then Goto wp-admin >>> settings >>> permalinks

Select "Custom Structure" and remove "index.php" only from it

Save and check ... It works perfectly!

thanks at all

Comment: How is your solution different from Scott's??

Answer (score 0):

I will extend the correct answer.

#### If you're using Apache webserver

**1.** First check on the Wordpress admin panel in Setting/Permalinks if you selected the desired way to show links.

**2.** Check if the file .htaccess on the DocumentRoot folder of your virtualhost has this code:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    # END WordPress
```

**3.** Check if in the Apache VirtualHost config you have correctly setup the `AllowOverride` option
It will work with `AllowOverride All` or `AllowOverride FileInfo All`

**3.** Check if the mod_rewrite module it's enabled in your Apache config

**4.** ¿Using FPM/FastCgi/Cgi PHP interpreter?

If you're using the PHP module of Apache you should be ok. But if you're using FPM/FastCgi/Cgi you should do this because Wordpress tries to detect if the mod_rewrite module it's enabled on Apache. But if you're not using the apache module that function wordpress uses returns nothing and it will think you don't have the mod_rewrite enabled.

So you should need to fake one function inside the functions.php of your theme. I suggest you to use a child-theme of your theme to avoid problems when updating.

You should add this code to the functions.php of your theme usually (wp-content/themes/<your_theme>/functions.php

```
add_filter('got_url_rewrite', 'enable_url_rewrite');
function enable_url_rewrite($got_url_rewrite) {
            return true;
}
```

#### If you're using Nginx

Check if you have a similar code inside the virtualhost. If not add it.

```
# if requested file doesn't exists, send to bootstrap
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

With nginx it will finish here, but if you continue to get problems check the last item of the Apache section.